# Ansible notify handlers in another role

Tags: ansible

Can I notify the handler in another role?  What should I do to make ansible find it?

The use case is, e.g. I want to configure some service and then restart it if changed.  Different OS have probably different files to edit and even the file format can be different.  So I would like to put them into different roles (because the file format can be different, it can't be done by setting group_vars).  But the way to restart the service is the same, using `service` module; so I'd like to put the handler to `common` role.

Is anyway to achieve this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 83):

You can also call handlers of a *dependency* role. May be cleaner than including files or explicitly listing roles in a playbook just for the purpose of role to role relationship. E.g.:

- roles/my-handlers/handlers/main.yml

  ```
  ---
  - name: nginx restart
    service: >
      name=nginx
      state=restarted
  ```
- roles/my-other/meta/main.yml

  ```
  ---
  dependencies:
  - role: my-handlers
  ```
- roles/my-other/tasks/main.yml

  ```
  ---
  - copy: >
      src=nginx.conf
      dest=/etc/nginx/
    notify: nginx restart
  ```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I tried with ansible-playbook `v1.9.0.1`.

Comment: Unfortunately even in 2.0 handling events seriously broken. I've fill few bugs on that:
    o https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/11694 (Include of handlers does nothing, even silence if file does not exists)
    o https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/11696 (ansible 2.0 yum and dnf modules does not fire notifications)
    o https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/11766 (On notify does not checked handler exist)

Comment: This is an excellent approach. The docs here (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#role-dependencies)  would be more helpful if it was explicitly mentioned that dependent roles have their handlers included.

Comment: This would also run tasks defined in `my_handlers` role.

Comment: Well, I've got role1 as dependency of role2 but I cannot fire role1's handlers from role2. I get the error: "The requested handler ... was not found in either the main handlers list nor in the listening handlers list".

Answer (score 36):

You should be able to do that if you include the handler file.

Example:

```
handlers:
  - include: someOtherRole/handlers/main.yml
```

But I don't think its elegant.

A more elegant way is to have a play that manages both roles, something like this:

```
- hosts: all
  roles:
  - role1
  - role2
```

This will make both roles able to call other handlers.

But again I would suggest to make it all in one role and separate files and use a conditional include http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditional-imports

Hope that helps

Comment: on 2.6.12 handlers are not implicitly shared. At least in my case.

Comment: In 2014 user *mpdehaan* [said](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/8553), "it is possible to define a handler twice without problem, for instance "restart apache", and the system will take the latest definition". However, my tests (Ansible 2.9.4) show that if handlers in different roles are defined, they are *both* run, but if they are defined only once, even if in a different role, they are still run, so in that since they are global. There is no need to import handlers from another role.

Answer (score 11):

You may import additional handlers from `YourRole/handlers/main.yml` file by using `import_tasks`.

So, if `MyRole` needs to call handlers in some `OtherRole`, `roles/MyRole/handlers/main.yml` will look like this:

```
- import_tasks: roles/OtherRole/handlers/main.yml
```

Of course `roles/MyRole/handlers/main.yml` may include additional handlers as well.

This way if I want to run `MyRole` without running tasks from the `OtherRole`, ansible will be able to correctly import and run handlers from the `OtherRole`

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, but needed to take many actions in the other dependent `roles`.

So rather than invoking the `handler` - we set a fact like so:

```
- name: install mylib to virtualenv
  pip: requirements=/opt/mylib/requirements.txt virtualenv={{ mylib_virtualenv_path }}
  sudo_user: mylib
  register: mylib_wheel_upgraded

- name: set variable if source code was upgraded
  set_fact:
    mylib_source_upgraded: true
  when: mylib_wheel_upgraded.changed
```

Then elsewhere in another `role`:

```
- name: restart services if source code was upgraded
  command: /bin/true
  notify: restart mylib server
  when: mylib_source_upgraded
```

Comment: No need to set a fact, a variable set through `register` has the same livespan as a fact.

Comment: @LukeAntins variables set through register pass through whatever "cruft" the module deems useful.  Setting a variable *you define* to a known value is much more predictable.  It decouples your playbook from specific module implementations, and from the use of specific modules to generate the variable.

Answer (score 2):

Currently I'm using ansible v2.10.3 and it supports to call `handlers` on different roles. This was because the `handlers` are visible on the play-level, as per [Ansible Docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_handlers.html#using-variables-with-handlers) says. You can see the docs mentioned that in the bottom-most point.

> handlers are play scoped and as such can be used outside of the role they are defined in.

FYI, I tested the solution i.e. calling other role's `handlers` and it works! No need to import or else, just **make sure that the roles are in the same playbook execution**.

To illustrate:

- `roles/vm/handlers/main.yaml`

  ```
  ---
  - name: rebootvm
    ansible.builtin.reboot:
      reboot_timeout: 600
      test_command: whoami
  ```
- `roles/config-files/tasks/main.yaml`

  ```
  ---
  - name: Copy files from local to remote
    ansible.builtin.copy:
      dest: /home/ubuntu/config.conf
      src: config.conf
      backup: yes
      force: yes
    notify:
      - rebootvm
  ```

So when the config file (i.e. `config.conf`) changed, Ansible will send it to the remote location and it will notify the handler `rebootvm`, then the VM is rebooted.

P.S. I don't know what version exactly Ansible support this.

Edit: code indentation fix